# cursor jumps to the end of the paragraph when I attempt to insert any number in the middle of it

Tags: cursor

I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.The cursor jumps to the end of the paragraph when I attempt to insert any number in the middle of any line of a paragraph; after the number is typed, the cursor gets re positioned at the very end of the paragraph for typing the following character.

This happens in any text editor (including any text editor online). This started happening ever since the Ubuntu boot screen started flickering with the following sequence displayed repeatedly:

```
(^[[4~^[[4~^[[4~^[[4~)
```

Has anyone else had the same problem? (I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my hard drive of my laptop after removing Windows 10 from it).

Comment: Are any of your keyboard keys stuck?